# How do I link my library with czmq using CMake

Tags: c, linux, cmake, zeromq

I am having trouble finding a way to linking the czmq library when using CMake. I can compile code using the czmq library with `gcc myprog.c -lczmq` just fine.

My project structure looks like this:

```
src/...
include/...
build/...
CMakeLists.txt
```

The `src/` folder contains the `.c` files and corresponding `.h` files. The `include/` folder contains the library header.

My current `CmakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(mylib)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

#Header
include_directories(include)

#Src files, GLOB allows for wildcard additions
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*c")

#Generate the shared library from the sources
add_library(mylib SHARED ${SOURCES})

#Set location for the library installation
install(TARGETS mylib DESTINATION .)
```

Comment: That duplicate didn't answer my question as I still have to add the `-lczmq` flag when I compile code that uses the library created.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` to whatever options you want the linker to use:

```
SET(GCC_LINK_FLAGS "-lczmq")
```

then append the flags to the CMake variables:

```
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
```

Comment: Variable `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` is a **wrong place** for `-l` flags: the content of this variable appears **before** the object file(s) in the linker's command line, while correct order of `-l` flags is **after** the object file(s). Command `target_link_libraries` should be used instead of `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`.